# WeifenLuo DockPanelSuite opening a new Document fails with Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

A very frustrating error is being thrown in the below code:

```
try
            {
                FrmRestrictedWebBrowser frmRWB2 = new FrmRestrictedWebBrowser();
                    frmRWB2.Show(dockPanel, DockState.Document);
                frmRWB2.ShowSrcUrl(eur.LinkUrl);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
```

**The Error: Stack trace**

> at
>   WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.FocusManagerImpl.SuspendFocusTracking()
>   at WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.SuspendLayout(Boolean
>   allWindows)    at
>   WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockContentHandler.Show(DockPanel
>   dockPanel, DockState dockState)    at
>   WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockContent.Show(DockPanel dockPanel,
>   DockState dockState)    at Imogen.frmMain.ProcessUnReported(EUReported
>   eur) in C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\Imogen\Imogen\frmMain.cs:line 244

**Error Message:**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

As you can see all I am doing is creating a new form and trying to show it.
Everything says that it is working until the .Show(dockPanel, DockState.Document) The Form and the dockPanel exist and have handles so I don't know what is going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the version of DPS you use?

Comment: @LexLi version 2.9.0.0